# Concatenate object items

Tags: php

I have the following function which works fine.

```
function ($objects, $items = array())
{
  $result = array();
  foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $result[$object->id] = $object->first_name . ' ' . $object->last_name; 
  }
  return $result;
}
```

However, I would like to pass in an array to $items, and have that exploded, so that I dont have to specify first_name and last_name manually.

If $item was only a single value (and not an array), then it would be simple:

```
$result[$object->id] = $object->$item;
```

But I have no idea how to make this work if $items contains multiple values and I want to join them with a space. Something like, the following, but I need to get the $object in there

```
$items = array('first_name', 'last_name');
$result[$object->id] = implode(' ', $items);
```

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: Well, each $result[$object->id] needs to be set to $object->item for each value in $items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do I get you right that you`d like to use the strings in $item as property-names of $object?

```
function ($objects, $items = array())
{
  $result = array();
  foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $valuesToAssign = array();
    foreach ($items as $property) {
        $valuesToAssign[] = $object->$property;
    }
    $result[$object->id] = implode(' ', $valuesToAssign);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

I have no idea to avoid the second foreach, but that gives you the desired result.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the inner foreach? There's nothing wrong with using two `foreach`s to iterate over two arrays!

Comment: Personally I don`t like nested foreach-loops. I hoped to see a solution where the values in $items could be used dynamically, but in the end you`re right. Though I would refactor the inner foreach to a second function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right, but how about this:

```
function foo($objects, $items = array()) {
    $result = array();
    $keys = array_flip($items);

    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        // Cast object to array, then omit all the stuff that is not in $items
        $values = array_intersect_key((array) $object, $keys);

        // Glue the pieces together
        $result[$object->id] = implode(' ', $values);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/l8vmGr

Comment: Added more detail to the question